# Shopify [Liquid] - Custom box for day-based banners

Tags: html, json, date, shopify, liquid

I was given the task to customize a box or create a section so we can put a primary image, that would be changed according to the settings. For example: I have picture1, and picture2. I want picture2 to show only on Weekends; furthermore, it would be nice to set up an expiration date, so even if we forget to deactivate it, our customers wont be mislead into thinking the promotion is still on.

I'm really new to the web-design world, so I took one of the boxes that already existed (and was somewhat close to what I wanted). I re-designed it, and it *works*, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

This is what I added to the box "simple".

```
{
    "type": "simple",
    "name": "Simple",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "link",
        "label": "Link"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "text",
        "label": "Title"
      },
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "image",
        "label": "Imagen principal"
      },
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "imagepar",
        "label": "Imagen de promoción"
      },
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Layout"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "width",
        "label": "Width",
        "default": "50",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "33",
            "label": "33%"
          },
          {
            "value": "50",
            "label": "50%"
          },
          {
            "value": "100",
            "label": "100%"
          }
        ]
      },
```

This is the part where you can select the days you want the promo to show. I sense it could be better. But as far as I know, Shopify doesn't have a date/day picker for boxes.

```
      {
    "type": "header",
    "content": "Elige los días"
     },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Lunes",
        "label": "Lunes",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Martes",
        "label": "Martes",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Miercoles",
        "label": "Miércoles",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Jueves",
        "label": "Jueves",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Viernes",
        "label": "Viernes",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Sabado",
        "label": "Sábado",
        "default": false
      },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "Domingo",
        "label": "Domingo",
        "default": false
      },
```

And now, where I call it:

```
{%- when 'simple' -%}
            {%- liquid
              assign block_img = ''
              assign block_text = ''
              if block.settings.link contains '/products/'
                assign product_handle = block.settings.link | remove: '/products/'
                assign block_img = all_products[product_handle].featured_media.preview_image
                assign block_text = all_products[product_handle].title
              elsif block.settings.link contains '/collections/'
                assign lang_code_string = request.locale.iso_code | prepend: '/'
                assign collection_handle = block.settings.link | remove: '/collections/' | remove: lang_code_string
                assign block_text = collections[collection_handle].title
                if collections[collection_handle].image
                  assign block_img = collections[collection_handle].image
                else
                  assign block_img = collections[collection_handle].products[0].featured_image
                endif
              endif
              if block.settings.text != ''
                assign block_text = block.settings.text
              endif
              assign todaynumber = 'now' | date: '%u'
              case todaynumber
                when '1'
                    if block.settings.Lunes
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                when '2'
                    if block.settings.Martes
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif                
                when '3'
                    if block.settings.Miercoles
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                when '4'
                    if block.settings.Jueves
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                when '5'
                    if block.settings.Viernes
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                when '6'
                    if block.settings.Sabado
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                when '7'
                    if block.settings.Domingo
                        assign checkday = true
                    endif
                endcase
              if block.settings.image
                if checkday
                    assign block_img = block.settings.imagepar
                else
                    assign block_img = block.settings.image
                endif
              endif
            -%}
```

So, as you can see I used the `case` statement, to check the today's date and ask if the checkbox is true. This works, but is far from pretty. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand you have 2 requests regarding the code you posted:

1. You want to tidy up your code
2. You want to add a check which will disable the promo feature after a set deadline

**Let's tidy up the code**

Use appropriate [specialized input settings](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#specialized-input-settings) for product and collection, rather than pasting URLs in the settings and manipulating the string.

Therefore replacing the setting with `"id": "link"` with the following:

```html
    "settings": [
      {
          "type": "product",
          "id": "product",
          "label": "Product",
          "info": "The image of this product will be used for the block"
      },
      {
          "type": "collection",
          "id": "collection",
          "label": "Collection",
          "info": "If no product is selected, the block image will be the collection image or the image of the first product of the collection"
      },
```

and then replacing the code manipulating the URL string with the following liquid code:

```html
    if block.settings.product
      assign block_text = product.title
      assign block_img = product.featured_media.preview_image
    elsif block.settings.collection
      assign block_text = collection.title
      if collection.image
        assign block_img = collection.image
      else
        assign block_img = collection.products[0].featured_media
      endif
    endif
```

**Let's implement the deadline check**

Let's add a text input setting as we don't have a date picker

```html
{
  "type": "text",
  "id": "deadline",
  "label": "deadline",
  "info": "Insert date in the format dd-mm-yyyy"
}
```

unfortunately, we are not able to do client-side validation on this input so we might use this setting in the liquid without trusting the user (better explained if the deadline input is not valid it behaves the same ad if the deadline has passed).

Basically not you have to parse the input text with the [split filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/split/) and compare it with `now`.
See your line `assign todaynumber = 'now' | date: '%u'`...
Once you have enclosed the comparison in a boolean you can wrap all our code so far produced in a big `if` statement using this variable.

I leave the implementation to you...

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't opened this and just recently looked at your answer. I'll implement it and see how it look. As today, I'm the only one that is modifying the deadline, so the validation is not that much of an issue (but I know is good practice).

Comment: If you think my answer was useful would you mind upvoting it, or marking it as "accepted answer" wheather that's the case?

Comment: I actually did upvote it, but my reputation is still too low for voting. Hope it goes up and you get the merit you deserve.